# How can I overlay a SwiftUI View to with top right corner (topTrailing) of a full screen Image and still be visible within the viewport of the device?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, overlay, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to create a view that presents a full screen `Image` and a `NavigationLink` in the top right corner overlayed on top of the image. However, I'm running into an issue such that the full screen `Image` somehow pushes the `NavigationLink` outside of the viewable part of the screen when I align the `NavigationLink` to the `.topTrailing` position. Here is the buggy code and the corresponding preview:

```swift
ZStack {
   Image("yose").resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
        OverviewButton()
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing).padding()
}
```

[image: NavigationLink not shown on screen]

When I comment out the full screen `Image`, the `NavigationLink` can be seen where I would like it to be. Also, if I align the `NavigationLink` to be `.bottom` or `.top`, it is within the viewable part of the screen as well. Code:

```swift
ZStack {
//   Image("yose").resizable()
//        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
        OverviewButton()
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing).padding()
}
```

Preview:

[image: NavigationLink in the correct spot]

How can I overlay the `NavigationLink` in the top right corner on top of the full screen image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's causing this, but using a `GeometryReader` instead of `.infinity` seems to fix the problem.

```
    GeometryReader { g in
        ZStack {
            Color(.red)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                Text("HI")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: g.size.width, maxHeight: g.size.height, alignment: .topTrailing)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this fix. 

Also not sure what's causing the problem, but I am curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a `ZStack` is determined by the size of its contents.

Since you are scaling the image to fill, the full image is (probably) going to be larger than the screen (unless the aspect ratio of the image exactly matches the aspect ratio of the screen). This is the size being adopted by the `ZStack`.

The `.frame` modifier being applied to the button is then making it occupy the same size as the image. So this is why it is going off-screen.

I would suggest applying the `Image` as background to the `ZStack` instead:

```swift
ZStack {
    NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
        OverviewButton()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
    .padding()
}
.background {
    Image("yose")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
}
```

You could also consider applying the button as an overlay to the parent container. This would be another way of positioning it in the top-right corner and might mean that a `ZStack` would not be needed any more:

```swift
ZStack { // or whatever container is suitable for the main content

    // main content

}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
    NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView()) {
        OverviewButton()
    }
    .padding()
}
.background {
    Image("yose")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
}
```